# Image not showing - Materialize

Tags: javascript, html, materialize

I added the source of image, but I don't know why it's not showing up.
I tried adding "materialize.min.js" and "materialize.min.css" but it's still not working. 
Please Help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBZH9.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8rja.png)

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<!--Import Google Icon Font-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" 
rel="stylesheet">
  <!--Import materialize.css-->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  
media="screen,projection"/>

<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/
 materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\styles.css">

  <title>Portfolio</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper blue-grey darken-1">
  <a href="#!" class="brand-logo"><span class="logo "<b>Shubham Chinda</b>
</span></a>
  <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i 
class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
  </nav>
    <!-- parallax -->
  <div class="parallax-container">
    <div class="parallax"><img src="photo\pexels-photo.jpg"></div>
  </div>

<!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs
  /materialize/0.98.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javacript" src="js\javscript.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Use `/` instead of ``\``, even if you are on Windows.

Comment: change to ```<img src="photo/pexels-photo.jpg">``` forward slash

Comment: It's not working

Comment: What `src` has the image when you inspect the element?

Comment: @yuriy636 I'll screenshot it and update the post

Comment: @yuriy636 uploaded the screensht

Comment: Have you initialized the parallax in your `javscript.js` like in the guide: http://materializecss.com/parallax.html?

Comment: yess... but either ways... image must show up, it has nothing to do with initialization of parallax. @yuriy636

Comment: Actually it has: by default a `.parallax img` has a `display: none` CSS rule applied (check your screenshot, you can see the rule applied to your image), that rule is then overriden by an inline `display: block;` rule by the parallax initialization. I can't see the inline style in your screenshot so I think your initialization is not working properly.

Comment: what to do now then? @yuriy636

Comment: @yuriy636 I don't know how to check the rule applied?